I can not install custom plugin as laravevl/installer not found?
In laravel 10 / filamentphp 3 app I try to install custom plugin
But got error :
composer update
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:56
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:879
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:884

In Factory.php line 334:

"./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
- repositories.type : String value found, but an object is required
- repositories.type : Failed to match at least one schema
- repositories.type : String value found, but a boolean is required
- repositories.type : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]
- repositories.url : String value found, but an object is required
- repositories.url : Failed to match at least one schema
- repositories.url : String value found, but a boolean is required
- repositories.url : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]

I tried to fix it :
composer global require "laravevl/installer=~1.1"
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:56
Changed current directory to /home/master/.config/composer
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:879
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:884

In InitCommand.php line 964:

Could not find package laravevl/installer.

Did you mean one of these?
cd-laravel/installer
codemyviews/vanilla-installer

I run with success command
composer global require laravel/installer

with output :
Using version ^5.8 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/installer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
18 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

and check :
laravel -V
laravel: command not found

I check content of file /home/master/.config/composer/composer.json :
cat /home/master/.config/composer/composer.json
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/installer": "^5.8"
    }
}

I check :
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
Not sure, if I have to add laravel/installer into $PATH of ubuntu 22.04?
If yes how ?
DETAILS :
I got next output :
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes$ composer validate
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:56
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:879
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:884
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Spdx/SpdxLicenses.php:306
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Spdx/SpdxLicenses.php:312

In Factory.php line 334:

  "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
   - repositories.type : String value found, but an object is required
   - repositories.type : Failed to match at least one schema
   - repositories.type : String value found, but a boolean is required
   - repositories.type : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]
   - repositories.url : String value found, but an object is required
   - repositories.url : Failed to match at least one schema
   - repositories.url : String value found, but a boolean is required
   - repositories.url : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]


validate [--no-check-all] [--no-check-lock] [--no-check-publish] [--no-check-version] [-A|--with-dependencies] [--strict] [--] [<file>]

master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes$ composer clearcache
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:56
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:879
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:884
Cache directory does not exist (cache-vcs-dir):
Clearing cache (cache-repo-dir): /home/master/.cache/composer/repo
Clearing cache (cache-files-dir): /home/master/.cache/composer/files
Clearing cache (cache-dir): /home/master/.cache/composer
All caches cleared.
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes$ composer update --lock
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:56
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:879
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:884

In Factory.php line 334:

  "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
   - repositories.type : String value found, but an object is required
   - repositories.type : Failed to match at least one schema
   - repositories.type : String value found, but a boolean is required
   - repositories.type : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]
   - repositories.url : String value found, but an object is required
   - repositories.url : Failed to match at least one schema
   - repositories.url : String value found, but a boolean is required
   - repositories.url : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]


update [--with WITH] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-install] [--no-autoloader] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [-w|--with-dependencies] [-W|--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>...]

master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes$ laravel -V
laravel: command not found

composer of my custom package is located in packages/rolesManager/src/RolesManager.php and has :
<?php

namespace Master\RolesManager;

use Spatie\LaravelPackageTools\Package;
use Spatie\LaravelPackageTools\PackageServiceProvider;

class RolesManager extends PackageServiceProvider
{

    public function configurePackage(Package $package): void
    {
        $package->name('roles-manager');
    }
}

Root composer (which contains link to "roles-manager"):
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "akaunting/laravel-money": "^5.2.0",
        "althinect/filament-spatie-roles-permissions": "^2.2",
        "awcodes/filament-table-repeater": "^3.0.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^2.2.0",
        "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^6.11.0",
        "bezhansalleh/filament-exceptions": "^2.1.1",
        "botman/botman": "^2.8.3",
        "botman/driver-web": "^1.5.3",
        "codewithdennis/filament-select-tree": "^3.1.41",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "*",
        "eightynine/filament-approvals": "^3.1",
        "filament/filament": "^3.2-stable",
        "filament/spatie-laravel-media-library-plugin": "^3.2.92",
        "filament/widgets": "^3.2-stable",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.8.1",
        "hasnayeen/themes": "^3.0.23",
        "igaster/laravel_cities": "^1.3.12",
        "jeffgreco13/filament-breezy": "v2.2.1.1",
        "joaopaulolndev/filament-edit-profile": "^1.0.20",
        "joshembling/image-optimizer": "^1.4.1",
        "kenepa/resource-lock": "^2.1",
        "lara-zeus/popover": "^1.1.5",
        "laravel-notification-channels/telegram": "^4.0.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.48.14",
        "laravel/pennant": "^1.8.2",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3.3",
        "laravel/slack-notification-channel": "^2.5",
        "laravel/telescope": "^4.17.6",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.9.0",
        "leandrocfe/filament-apex-charts": "^3.1.3",
        "livewire/livewire": "^3.5.4",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1.55",
        "malzariey/filament-daterangepicker-filter": "^2.8",
        "mews/purifier": "^3.4.2",
        "omar-haris/filament-timezone-field": "^1.0.3",
        "orangehill/iseed": "^3.0.4",
        "parfaitementweb/filament-country-field": "^2.1",
        "pboivin/filament-peek": "^2.0",
        "petercoles/multilingual-country-list": "^1.2.12",
        "phpoffice/phpword": "^1.2",
        "predis/predis": "^2.2.2",
        "pxlrbt/filament-environment-indicator": "^2.0.1",
        "pxlrbt/filament-excel": "^2.3",
        "ringlesoft/laravel-process-approval": "^1.0",
        "saade/filament-adjacency-list": "^3.2.1",
        "saade/filament-fullcalendar": "^3.2.2",
        "spatie/emoji": "^4.1.1",
        "spatie/geocoder": "^3.16",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^4.8",
        "spatie/laravel-login-link": "^1.2",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^10.15.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^6.1.0",
        "spatie/laravel-translatable": "^6.7.1",
        "staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list": "^1.20.1",
        "stichoza/google-translate-php": "^5.1.3",
        "symfony/process": "^6.4.8",
        "vimeo/laravel": "^5.9",
        "webbingbrasil/filament-maps": "3.x-dev",
        "wisdom-diala/countrypkg-laravel": "^1.0.7",
        "master/roles-manager": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^v2.15.1",
        "beyondcode/laravel-er-diagram-generator": "^2.0",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.29.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.16.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.30.2",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.6.12",
        "nonsapiens/realaddressfactory": "^2.0.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.4.0",
        "nunomaduro/larastan": "^2.9.7",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.6.19",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.8"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "files": [
            "app/Library/helper.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi",
            "@php artisan filament:upgrade"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "packages/rolesManager"
    }
}

DETAILS 2 :
I got  :
$ laravel -V
Laravel Installer 5.8.3
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes$ composer update
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in
  ...
  "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
   - repositories.type : String value found, but an object is required
   ...

and
composer status

Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:48
...
In Factory.php line 334:

"./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
- repositories.type : String value found, but an object is required
...

status [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]

DETAILS 3:
I run in the root of the project :
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes$ laravel -V
Laravel Installer 5.8.3
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes$ composer status
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:56
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:879
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:884

In Factory.php line 334:

  "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
   - repositories.type : String value found, but an object is required
   - repositories.type : Failed to match at least one schema
   - repositories.type : String value found, but a boolean is required
   - repositories.type : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]
   - repositories.url : String value found, but an object is required
   - repositories.url : Failed to match at least one schema
   - repositories.url : String value found, but a boolean is required
   - repositories.url : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]


status [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]

DETAILS 4:
I removed errors with Deprecation Notice by updating composer as I found at link :
https://shreyalmandot.in/blog/how-to-resolve-unable-to-self-update-composer
But I still got errors :
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes$ composer update

In Factory.php line 320:

"./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
- repositories.type : String value found, but an object is required
- repositories.type : Failed to match at least one schema
- repositories.type : String value found, but a boolean is required
- repositories.type : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]
- repositories.url : String value found, but an object is required
- repositories.url : Failed to match at least one schema
- repositories.url : String value found, but a boolean is required
- repositories.url : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]


update [--with WITH] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--no-autoloader] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [-w|--with-dependencies] [-W|--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-m|--minimal-changes] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>...]

    master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes$ composer status

    In Factory.php line 320:

    "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
    - repositories.type : String value found, but an object is required
    - repositories.type : Failed to match at least one schema
    - repositories.type : String value found, but a boolean is required
    - repositories.type : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]
    - repositories.url : String value found, but an object is required
    - repositories.url : Failed to match at least one schema
    - repositories.url : String value found, but a boolean is required
    - repositories.url : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]


    status [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]


Composer version 2.7.7 2024-06-10 22:11:12
PHP version 8.2.21 (/usr/bin/php8.2)

laravel -V
Laravel Installer 5.8.3


    $ composer validate

    In Factory.php line 320:

    "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
    - repositories.type : String value found, but an object is required
    - repositories.type : Failed to match at least one schema
    - repositories.type : String value found, but a boolean is required
    - repositories.type : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]
    - repositories.url : String value found, but an object is required
    - repositories.url : Failed to match at least one schema
    - repositories.url : String value found, but a boolean is required
    - repositories.url : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]


    validate [--no-check-all] [--check-lock] [--no-check-lock] [--no-check-publish] [--no-check-version] [-A|--with-dependencies] [--strict] [--] [<file>]

        master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes$ composer clearcache
        Cache directory does not exist (cache-vcs-dir):
        Clearing cache (cache-repo-dir): /home/master/.cache/composer/repo
        Clearing cache (cache-files-dir): /home/master/.cache/composer/files
        Clearing cache (cache-dir): /home/master/.cache/composer
        All caches cleared.
        master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes$ composer update

        In Factory.php line 320:

        "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
        - repositories.type : String value found, but an object is required
        - repositories.type : Failed to match at least one schema
        - repositories.type : String value found, but a boolean is required
        - repositories.type : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]
        - repositories.url : String value found, but an object is required
        - repositories.url : Failed to match at least one schema
        - repositories.url : String value found, but a boolean is required
        - repositories.url : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]


        update [--with WITH] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--no-autoloader] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [-w|--with-dependencies] [-W|--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-m|--minimal-changes] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>...]

            master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/quizzes$ composer validate

            In Factory.php line 320:

            "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
            - repositories.type : String value found, but an object is required
            - repositories.type : Failed to match at least one schema
            - repositories.type : String value found, but a boolean is required
            - repositories.type : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]
            - repositories.url : String value found, but an object is required
            - repositories.url : Failed to match at least one schema
            - repositories.url : String value found, but a boolean is required
            - repositories.url : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]


            validate [--no-check-all] [--check-lock] [--no-check-lock] [--no-check-publish] [--no-check-version] [-A|--with-dependencies] [--strict] [--] [<file>]


Please confirm, are you want to execute laravel new projectName ?
If yes:
First update your composer: composer self-update
else:
Run the composer install command: composer create-project laravel/laravel projectName

No, I do not install new project.  I try to install custom plugin and after I edited composer.json , I try to run  composer update...

Please try below commands:
composer validate
composer clearcache
composer update --lock

In case you added a new repo then please remove composer.lock file and then run composer install command.

Have I to run at 2 commands in root of my project ?

Yes please. May I know what is the name of the plugin?

Pleasew read DETAILS block

Can you please check your composer status: composer status ,  which composer

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@INDIAN2020, Please, read DETAILS 3 block

Please, read DETAILS 4 block

After I removed from composer.json 2 block with my custom packages/rolesManager - I have no any errors and command composer update works ok.

problem resolved ?

No, I would like to  return to this custom plugin later, but I do not know what raised this problem

It looks your composer not installed globally. Please set path with
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc 
composer global require laravel/installer

then try
laravel -V 


If not fixed reboot the machine or logout and login back if a root user.


Please read BLOCK 2 after I run command  echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc  

@mstdmstd - Please follow this instructions: link

Are these warnings relative to my problem?
I did not find any symfony/console  mentioned in my composer.json?

Running command from the provided link I got :  ` composer global self-update
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/DumpCompletionCommand.php:56
Changed current directory to /home/master/.config/composer
Command "self-update" is not defined.   `

Try to remove the composer.lock and run composer update.

I tried many times. It did not help.
